# Getting comma separated month for a given from month and to month using recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

We have requirement where 2 months and 2 years are provided as input. And the result should provide a comma separated month-year all the months between the from month-year and to month-year.

Say, we have

```
From Month is 'Jan' 
From Year is 2011
To Month is 'Apr'
To Year is 2011
```

desired output

```
Jan'11,Feb'11,Mar'11,Apr'11
```

Can this be achieved using recursive CTE? We need to achieve this using recursive CTE. Could somebody help me on this.

Comment: Why the specific recursive CTE requirement?

Comment: We have already created a function to achieve the same. But performance and to mitigate other issues, we are going for recursive CTE.

Comment: That rules out some other potential approaches such as `XML PATH` which might (or might not) be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
--declaration of variables
declare @frommonth char(3) = 'jan',@fromyear char(4) = 2011,
        @tomonth char(3) = 'APR', @toyear char(4) = 2011
         
declare @output varchar(max)
declare @f int, @t int 

select --setting from and to month as months after 1900-01-01
@f = datediff(month, 0, cast('1' +@frommonth+@fromyear as datetime)),
@t = datediff(month, 0, cast('1' +@tomonth+@toyear as datetime))

-- recusive loop
;with cte as
(
select @f m
union all
select m + 1 from cte
where m < @t
)
select @output = coalesce(@output +',', '') +stuff(convert(varchar(11),dateadd(mm, m, 0), 109), 4, 6, '''') FROM CTE

select @output
```

Result:

```
Jan'11,Feb'11,Mar'11,Apr'11
```

Test here:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/114801/declaration-of-variables

Comment: Thats great one. Thank you very much